How to highlight text using puppeteer
Is there a way to Highlight text using puppeteer? I want to highlight text like shown in the image and take screenshots. Is it possible to do with puppeteer?
I have tried loading and extracting text but I don't see a way to highlight text. If not possible do I have to do this post-processing? I would love to do this as a video capture though.

An example page would be
https://www.webmd.com/heart-disease/heart-disease-symptoms
I want to highlight important areas of the page and create a video. The idea is to highlight what can be done as an animation and screen-record to create the video.
It should look like this
https://youtu.be/BwgnWoZZ4A8?t=96

Where did the text come from?  Is this from a web site?  Do you want to do highlighting by hand, or automated?

Please add details: a site, expected result, Puppeteer code so far, package.json, etc. See [mcve] for guidance. Thanks! BTW, this probably doesn't have much to do with Puppeteer. Just inject <span>s where you want them and add CSS to add highlighting.

I have added details. I would like to do it in an automated way.
